# Http inbound channel adapter responds to too many paths

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-rest

I have a working spring integration application, to which I added an HTTP endpoint under `/requests` to receive POST data from a REST client (a web browser actually); I'm adding a set of other REST endpoints by means of *Spring MVC* too, one of which handles GET requests to `/api/requests` — these REST endpoints se are meant to provide a read-only interaction to the clients.

The spring integration endpoint works when invoked as expected (i.e. with a direct call to `/requests`), but I'm experiencing that it is "catching" even requests it should not: i.e. `/api/requests`.

I'm not using Spring Boot. I adapter my configuration from the example on the [Integration home](https://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/), moving it from an application to a web application later on.

This is the `context.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:...>

    <ctx:component-scan base-package="services,api"  />

    <int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="httpInboundAdapter"
        channel="httpRequestsChannel"
        path="/requests"
        supported-methods="POST">
        <int-http:cross-origin allow-credentials="false" allowed-headers="*" origin="*" />
    </int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <!-- other channels and endpoints -->

    <!-- misc beans -->

    <!-- other beans: jdbc-datasource, etc -->

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

</beans>
```

And the (relevant parts of the) `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">

    <!-- [a] -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>httpInboundAdapter</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!-- [b] -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>httpInboundAdapter</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/requests</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/META-INF/spring.integration/context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Preliminary questions:

1. is the servlet in `[a]` configured correctly? This works, but it's not clear to me which servlet name should match which bean name (as said in [Http Inbound Components](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html#http-inbound)), perhaps it's *context bean id* ↔ *web.xml servlet name*?
2. is the mapping in `[b]` necessary? I couldn't get the inbound adapter to work without it, but maybe it should be configured in another way as the above mentioned docs show no mapping for the `HttpRequestHandlerServlet` servlet

And the main question:

3. why is that adapter intercepting other rest calls? I'm getting:

   ```
   HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported
   ```

   when calling `/api/requests` which clearly shows the adapter stepping in.

I did some debugging, and the behaviour seems controlled by `UrlPathHelper.alwaysUseFullPath` that changes "/api/requests" to "/requests".
If this property could be set to `true` the whole would work, how could I do that?

---

### UPDATE #1

I've updated my configuration after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50157542/3127111), but I still have troubles.

I get a 404 from the client request and this warning appears on the application log:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/requests] in DispatcherServlet with name 'app'
```

This is the new `context.xml` with new `id`s:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:...>

    <ctx:component-scan base-package="services,api"  />
    <ctx:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="/api/requests"
        channel="httpRequestsChannel"
        path="/api/requests"
        supported-methods="POST">
        <int-http:cross-origin allow-credentials="false" allowed-headers="*" origin="*" />
    </int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="/api/requests"
        channel="nullChannel"
        path="/api/requests"
        supported-methods="OPTIONS">
        <int-http:cross-origin allow-credentials="false" allowed-headers="*" origin="*" />
    </int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <!-- other channels and endpoints -->

    <!-- misc beans -->

    <!-- other beans: jdbc-datasource, etc -->

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

</beans>
```

And I removed the servlet declaration and mapping from the `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- ... -->
```

---

### UPDATE #2

Another review, removing the duplicate id bean, I still get the same warning:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/requests] in DispatcherServlet with name 'app'
```

This is the new `context.xml` with new `id`s:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:...>

        <ctx:component-scan base-package="services,api"  />
        <ctx:annotation-config />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="/api/requests"
            channel="httpRequestsChannel"
            path="/api/requests"
            supported-methods="POST,OPTIONS">
            <int-http:cross-origin allow-credentials="false" allowed-headers="*" origin="*" />
        </int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>

        <int:channel id="httpRequestsChannel" />
    <!-- other channels, endpoints and beans -->

</beans>
```

---

### UPDATE #3

As pointed out, I've edited the `path` attribute: POST requests work now, but GET requests are now broken, producing:

```
WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

While not shown above, this is the same application as in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50228090/3127111), here's the controller that should respond to `GET`s over `/api/requests`:

```java
package api;

// imports

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api/requests", produces="application/json")
public class RequestController {
    // ...
```

Edited `context.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:...>

        <ctx:component-scan base-package="services,api"  />
        <ctx:annotation-config />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="/api/requests"
            channel="httpRequestsChannel"
            path="/requests"
            supported-methods="POST,OPTIONS">
            <int-http:cross-origin allow-credentials="false" allowed-headers="*" origin="*" />
        </int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>

        <int:channel id="httpRequestsChannel" />
    <!-- other channels, endpoints and beans -->

</beans>
```

---

### UPDATE #4

In this update I fixed the REST controller main path mapping from `path="/api/requests"` to `path="/requests"`.

```java
package it.cgt.api;

// imports

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/requests", produces="application/json")
public class RequestController {

    @Autowired
    private RequestService requestService;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping(path= "")
    public ApiResponse<List<Request>> getRequests(RequestFilters filters) {
        return new ApiResponse<List<Request>>(requestService.getRequests(filters));
    }

    // ...
```

This change made `GET`s work again, but then `POST`s do not work anymore.

This seems due to the code in `DispatcherServlet#getHandler()`, where an instance of type `RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping` from the `handlerMappings` member recognizes the request to `/api/requests` but rejects the POST method throwing an exception that makes the execution fall outside the request handler lookup.

Answer (score 1):

In that documentation we have this sentence:

> If you are running within a Spring MVC application, then the aforementioned explicit servlet definition is not necessary.

Since you have a `DispatcherServlet`, you don't need that specific `HttpRequestHandlerServlet` for your `httpInboundAdapter`.

Therefore you also remove that `<url-pattern>/requests</url-pattern>` and all the REST API will be under `/api/*` and there won't be exposed `/requests` based on the mentioned `UrlPathHelper.alwaysUseFullPath`.

Comment: Can you please share an example? I tried to modify my configuration (see _Update #1_), but I think I'm not getting the `In that case, the bean name for your gateway can be matched against the URL path just like a Spring MVC Controller bean.` documentation part in [Http Inbound Components](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-inbound).

Comment: You can’t use the same `id` for several beans - only the las one will be available in the application context in the end.

Comment: I did it (please see _Update #2_) but I still get the 404; keep in mind that I'm new to Spring, MVC & Integration.

Comment: Since in `web.xml` you have `<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>`, try to map your channel adapter  like ` path="/requests"`. See some sample here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/http

Comment: Done. Is Spring doing suffix matching here? Anyway this fixed `POST`s, but broke `GET`s (I know they weren't shown in this question, please refer to _Update #3_)

Comment: You have an application Web context from the target Servlet container. Then you have an URL mapping from the servlet definition. All your target mappings go already lower, therefore you shouldn't repeat `/api` in the target handlers definitions. Otherwise your url should be like `/api/api/requests`. The GET should be considered in the separate thread.

Comment: A-ha! I was completely missing that, thank you. I fixed my controller configuration. Alas! `POST`s are broken again. Debugging I found a possible source though: the wrong handler claims to handle the request, but then rejects it (please see _Update #4_), is it a bug?

Comment: I think you need to have a separate paths for `@RestController` and channel Adapter. Now you are confusing a dispatcher.